# How do I resolve Windows Kits related errors for ARM64 in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, windows-arm64

I'm migrating a project from X64 to native ARM64. As I build the project after changing the config settings to ARM64, I see the following errors which otherwise produced clean build in X64 config.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\winbase.h(9736,32): error C2065: 'InterlockedIncrement64': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\winbase.h(9747,28): error C3861: '_InterlockedDecrement': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\winbase.h(9846,28): error C3861: '_InterlockedExchangeAdd': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\winbase.h(9858,31): error C3861: 'InterlockedExchangeAdd64': identifier not found
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\winnt.h(8752,19): error C3861: 'ReadNoFence8': identifier not found
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\winnt.h(8763,21): error C3861: 'ReadAcquire8': identifier not found
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\winnt.h(8774,21): error C3861: 'ReadNoFence8': identifier not found
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\winnt.h(8807,5): error C3861: 'WriteRelease8': identifier not found
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\winnt.h(8820,5): error C3861: 'WriteNoFence8': identifier not found
```

I use Visual Studio 2019 Professional & the following are the packages I installed for supporting the ARM64 config:

```
.NET Framework 4.8.1, which has ARM64 support.
C++ Universal Windows Platform Support for v142 build tools (ARM64)
C++/CLI support for v142 build tools (Latest)
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ ARM64 build tools (Latest)
C++ ATL for latest v142 build tools (ARM64)
C++ MFC for latest v142 build tools (ARM64)
```

I haven't used those APIs in my project, but unable to find why I get those errors.
Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried VS 2022, should be much better for ARM64 support. Are you even sure all this is even supported with VS 2019, as you seems to need C++/CLI/managed code above all? AFAIK, it's difficult to find clear statement from Microsoft.

Comment: I tried VS2022, but the result was same.
Do you think I need to build this on ARM64 device?
Or is it fine to build on Intel with ARM64 config selected in VS 2022/2019?
Thanks.

Comment: Building for ARM64 an different processor is a fully supported scenario (you just can't run it of course). However, I'm really unsure for C++/CLI on ARM64 (see for example https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4975) Can you provide a simple reproducing sample?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the Doc:[Get started with Arm64 Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-on-arm-devices?view=vs-2022#get-started-with-arm64-visual-studio)

> To get started with the native Arm64 Visual Studio experience:
>
> 1,Ensure you have an Arm64 device with Windows 11.
>
> 2,Uninstall any prior versions of Visual Studio from your Arm64 device.
>
> 3,Download and install the latest version Visual Studio 2022.

I suggest you could try to use `Visual Studio 2022` instead of `Visual Studio 2019`.

Comment: Is it mandatory to have an ARM64 device?
Can I cross compile from Intel device selecting ARM64 configuration?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you should make sure you have an Arm64 device with Windows 11. The Visual Studio Installer detects if the system architecture is Arm64 and if so, it downloads and installs the Arm64 version of Visual Studio on your Arm64 device (support is for Windows 11).

Comment: the errors was from windows sdk headers. vs studio version here absolute unrelated at all

Comment: and i have no arm64 device. but can without problem build arm64 code

Comment: You don't need an ARM64 device to compile an ARM64 binary.